# How to "relate" elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was wondering how you could "relate" two HTML elements.
For example, let's say a user clicks on a selection item and I want the element "related" to that element disappear.

```
<div id="game1Selection">I pick team1</div>
<div id="game2Selection">I pick team2</div>

<div id="game1">This is game 1</div>
<div id="game2">This is game 2</div>
```

What I would want to happen is that when a user selects "game1Selection" that the div "game1" will disappear and the same thing for game2, game3, etc. I know how to do this the long way:

```
$('#game1Selection').click( function() {
  $('#game1').toggleClass('selected');
});  //selected has the attribute display:none
```

How could I make two of them related so I don't have to write it the long way and just use `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/ezejac/1/edit)*

```
$('div[id$=Selection]').click(function(){
   var myID = this.id.split('Selection')[0];
   $('#'+myID).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

use the *ends with* selector `$` and retrieve the first part of the **ID** name by splitting the original ID and getting the first (`[0]`) part of the name **(gameN)**

---

### *[a better idea demo](http://jsbin.com/ezejac/5/edit)*

**But a far better example would be using this HTML**:

```
<div>
    <div class="selection">I pick team1</div>
    <div class="selection">I pick team2</div>
</div>

<div class="game">This is game 1</div>
<div class="game">This is game 2</div>
```

and retrieve the clicked element `index()` and find the matching element using `.eq()` :

```
$('.selection').click(function(){
   var i = $(this).index();
   $('.game').removeClass('selected').eq(i).addClass('selected');
});
```

This will allow you to remove the already `selected` classes and assign it to the *index-matching* element.

Comment: This works and I've personally used it in the past, but be aware that using a class like @user1689607 suggests is probably better/faster in terms of performance.

Comment: @Mahn I personally agree with you, but not always you can do some crucial changes to your HTML specially if it's returned by a messy php. Added a new demo. thanks

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the second method is that it's fragile (will break if the DOM is rearranged).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any way were you can have multiple selections at once?

Answer (score 1):

Use classes for like behavior, and grab the number from the id.

```
<div id="game1Selection" class="selection">I pick team1</div>
<div id="game2Selection" class="selection">I pick team2</div>

<div id="game1" class="game">This is game 1</div>
<div id="game2" class="game">This is game 2</div>
```

---

```
$('.selection').click( function() {
    $("#" + this.id.replace("Selection", "")).toggleClass('selected');
    $('.game').not(this).removeClass('selected');
});
```

Comment: @steveax as far as I can tell this will only break if the class/ids are changed, not the DOM order.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use HTML5's `data-*` properties to make the association more explicit:

```html
<div class="selector" data-fadetarget="game1">I pick team1</div>
<div class="selector" data-fadetarget="game2">I pick team2</div>

<div id="game1">This is game 1</div>
<div id="game2">This is game 2</div>
```

JavaScript:

```js
$('.selector').click( function() {
    var target = '#' + $(this).data('fadetarget');
    $(target).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

Using this method, the associations are explicit in the markup and won't fail if things are rearranged.